# How to simplify this RCode especially the for loops, to speed up?

Tags: r

I'm checking a df with 10000 rows and 6000 columns if there are similar strings (here: a,b,c) to my reference.
I want to count the similar strings for each row.

My problem is that the for loops, especially the first one, are very slow. I already changed the name_dat[,a] like in the previous "speed up" reviews but it was still not fast enough. Im looking for smarter way without checking each string from each row and column. Maybe there is a way to make rowwise comparisons?

```
x <- data.frame("name" = c("one","two","three"), "X1" = c("c","c","b"), "X2" = c("b","b","a"), "X3" = c("a","c","b"), "X4" = c("b","c","b"),stringsAsFactors = F)
y <- data.frame("name" = c("reference"), "X1" = c("c"), "X2" = c("a"), "X3" = c("b"), "X4" = c("b"),stringsAsFactors = F)

sum_list <- list() 
df <- y[-1,-1]  #df only with colnames

for (a in 1:length(x[,1])) {
  name_dat <- x[a,][-1]

      for (b in 1:length(x[,-1])) {
            n <- name_dat[,b]
            m <- y[-1][,b]

            if (n == m) {name_dat[,b] <- n}
            else  {name_dat[,b] <- NA} 
      } # end first loop
  sum_list[[a]] <- length(x[,-1]) - rowSums(is.na(name_dat))   
} #end second loop
```

With the sum_list i can make a result df with the number of similar strings. But i hope for a better/faster way mabe with the apply functions but i dont know how this can work for strings

Comment: Seems like it might be a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Use `stringi` package for string operations, it's vectorized.

Comment: Also, use `apply/sapply` rather than explicit loops, esp. nested loops.

Comment: @duckmayr i think i'll send it also to the codereview.

Comment: and i will look if i check the stringi package .. and finally learn how to work with apply functions.. thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry but you don't know how to do [basic indexing into a dataframe/array/matrix](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Index-matrices). For a dataframe x, you can directly reference `x[a,b]`. Also: `1:length(x[,1])` is just `1:nrow(x)` and `1:length(x[,-1])` is just `1:ncol(x)`. But you don't need to manually construct indices `a,b`. You don't need to manually index into `name_dat <- x[a,][-1]` ... `n <- name_dat[,b]`. Just directly reference `x[a,b]`. But you don't need to any of that at all, just use `sapply/apply` or a vectorized stringi function to sweep over `x`.